# Using a vector of thread in another thread : error attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stl, stdthread

I'm trying to send a vector to parameter of another thread's function :

```
void foo(){}
const int n = 24;
void Thread_Joiner(std::vector<thread>& t,int threadNumber)
{
    //some code
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<thread> threads(n, thread(foo));
    thread Control_thread1(Thread_Joiner, threads, 0);//error
    thread Control_thread2(Thread_Joiner, threads, 1);//error
    //...
}
```

The above code give this error :

```
: attempting to reference a deleted function
```

I checked  the header file of `std::thread`  It seems that copy constructor is deleted : `thread(const thread&) = delete;`

`std::thread` have a move constructor but I don't think in this case using move is helpfull because `Control_thread1` and `Control_thread2` use same `vector` !

If I use `thread **threads;...` instead of that `vector` It works fine but I don't want to use **pointers** .

What should I do ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::thread` copies the arguments used for the bind. Use `std::ref` to contain it as a reference:

```
std::thread Control_thread1(Thread_Joiner, std::ref(threads), 0);
std::thread Control_thread2(Thread_Joiner, std::ref(threads), 1);
```

Comment: @xyz The constructor of your vector is also attempting to copy a `thread(foo)` object.

Comment: well that's the question how can I fix that ?! using `vector<thread*>` ?

Comment: @xyz Yes, but it's preferable to use smart pointers: `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::thread>> threads(n, std::make_shared<std::thread>(foo))`. And if you're not intending to extend the vector past its declared size, use `std::array<24, std::shared_ptr<std::thread>>`

Comment: @xyz Actually all you need is `std::vector<std::thread> threads; for (auto& th : threads) th = std::thread(foo);`.

Comment: @xyz I know but it was wrong of me to suggest using `shared_ptr`  when it works fine without. [See this example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdbdaf2255da414d)